# ownCloud. Не монтируется SMB ресурс

Tags: samba, owncloud

Всем доброго времени. Пытаюсь найти решения для раздачи файлов офисным сотрудникам которым нужен удаленный доступ. Вот вроде нашел отличное решение: ownCloud, но когда в настройках создаю внешний ресурс, указываю smb ресурс, он просто не подключается.

Сначала проблема была в том, что не стоял php-smbclient. Поставил, теперь в логах абсолютная тишина. Включил дебаг в samba на сервере. ownCloud подключается, аутентифицируется под указанным пользователем и более ничего.

Может у кого работает такая связка? В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: у меня работает owncloud, И раньше я использовал с samba. Свою задачу выполняло. Что может быть? а что угодно, вполне возможно, что оно работает, просто Вы ещё этого не поняли:)

Comment: Ресурс на samba или windows? Я к тому что если это два Linux сервера может проще и надёжнее nfs настроить?

Comment: И второй момент: у пользователя под которым монтируете - доступ на smb ресурс есть?

Comment: Ресурс на Windows. Но пробовал уже и на samba поднять.
При этом я писал для теста скрипт который использует php-libsmbclient и он отлично подключается к серверу. А вот ownCloud не хочет.
Монтировать пробую от админа домена уже, все бестолку.

Comment: KoVadim а можно узнать на какой версии у вас все работает?
Я так-же подключил пользователей из AD (по ldap) и хочу что-бы сетевые ресурсы монтировались именно под учетной записью вошедшего в ownCloud.

Comment: у меня 9.1.1. Но ldap  я не подключал (этого мне не нужно)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Установил owncloud версии 8, все работает.
Разобрался.

В строке общий ресурс надо было прописать просто слэш (/)
Плюс в готовом дистрибутиве с сайта который под Ubuntu php-libsmbclient не стоит и ставится только из исходников.

Теперь все работает.